# How to check minimum hardware requirements in Java Project using wix3.8 installer?

Tags: java, wix, installation, custom-action, gradlew

I am working on a Java project which is built using gradlew. The installer is created with WiX 3.8.

While installing I need to check minimum hardware requirements (the system needs 2GB RAM and minimum storage capacity of disk is 2GB). For this check I have created a custom action in C#, calculated RAM and disk size (using `System.IO` and `System.Windows.Forms`) and it works fine.

The problem is that to run this C# custom action we need to install .NET Framework.

Is there any better way for this issue (other than C# custom action) without installing .NET Framework?